# I am getting an error while using Django ManyToManyField

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

in view.py

```
def watchlist(request, item_id):
    list=get_object_or_404(Listing, id=item_id)
    wc=WatchCount(user=request.user)
    if WatchCount.objects.filter(user=request.user, listing=list).exists():
        wc.listing.remove(list)
    else:
        wc.listing.add(list)     
    return HttpResponseRedirect(wc.get_absolute_url())
```

in models.py

```
class WatchCount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    listing =  models.ManyToManyField(Listing, blank=True, related_name="watchcount")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"
    def count(self):
        return self.listing.count()
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list', kwargs={'item_id': self.pk})
```

**ERROR:**

"<WatchCount: jeelen>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: Visit [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) scroll a bit, they have discussed this point. `ValueError: "<Article: Django lets you build Web apps easily>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: Have a look into Django user's guide:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
It may be that your two objects are not linked when you created them.

Answer (score 0):

before you want to add or remove ManyToMany Fields you need to create the object.
when you haven't created an object you can't add or remove ManyToMany fields because it doesn't have an id and it's not saved in database.
when an object is saved in database then database will set an id for it automatically.
so in your case `wc=WatchCount(user=request.user)` is created in your django code but it's not saved to the database so it doesn't have an id.
`wc.save()` will add the object to database then you can add or remove ManyToMany Fields.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating WatchCount object but you didnt save it...when you create objects like wc=WatchCount(user=request.user) you are  creating python object but didnt insert it in database...you need to save it first :
`we.save()`
then you can use remove or add.